# MySqlCommand removed all parameter values

Tags: c#, mysql, windows

I have a problem with `MySqlParamters` in C#. I will create a new entry in the database, but `MySqlCommand` writes only null-values.

```
    MySqlCommand see = new MySqlCommand("REPLACE INTO users (login, email) VALUES (@login,@email)",this.dbcontext);

            MySqlParameter p1 = new MySqlParameter("@login",MySqlDbType.VarChar,20);
            p1.Value = "Hello";

MySqlParameter p2 = new MySqlParameter("@email", "Dude");

            see.Parameters.Add(p1);
            see.Parameters.Add(p2);

            Console.WriteLine(p2.Value);

            see.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The entry in my database is

```
login   email
------------------
null    null
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't the MySql connector use `?` for parameters? (`@` are user variables) - so:

```
using(var see = new MySqlCommand(
    "REPLACE INTO users (login, email) VALUES (?login,?email)",this.dbcontext))
{
    MySqlParameter p1 = new MySqlParameter("login",MySqlDbType.VarChar,20);
    p1.Value = "Hello";
    MySqlParameter p2 = new MySqlParameter("email", "Dude");
    see.Parameters.Add(p1);
    see.Parameters.Add(p2);
    see.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or if you like some "dapper":

```
this.dbcontext.Execute(
    "REPLACE INTO users (login, email) VALUES (?login,?email)",
    new { login = "Hello", email = "Dude" }
);
```

Comment: Hey Marc, that´s it!  Thx

Answer (score -1):

see this...

[Find and Replace text in the entire table using a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-all-table-using-mysql-query)
[MySQL Replace query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440392/mysql-replace-query)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: None of these are even remotely related to the question

Comment: i need your help Marc. i want how to do upload and download files to database in asp.net c# using attribute based encryption and decryption...